# Xamarin android: Prepare APK file of last build check-in in TFS VS2017

Tags: xamarin.android, apk

I have checked-in code in TFS long ago, mean while i have modified multiple files and those changes are not reviewed so i can't make APK file for this uncompleted build. How i can make APK file of last check-in build, without doing `undo` my recent changes in visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is adding a new workspace and get the last or specific version of the source files. Thus the changes in your current workspace will keep there.

1. Add a new workspace and map source to a new folder, see [Add, edit,
   or remove a workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/create-work-workspaces#add-edit-or-remove-a-workspace) for details. (*Note that, do not get latest
   when you create a new workspace if you want to get the specific
   version*)
2. Switch to the new added workspace. See [Switch workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/create-work-workspaces#switch-workspaces)
3. In the left panel of `Source Control Explorer`, right click on the
   `Team Project` --> `Advanced` --> `Get Specific Version...` --> Select
   version type (e.g ChangeSet) and find the specific version --> `Get`

[image]

Comment: thank you. If i add another workspace it means i need to have space in my drive as big as my project(to take latest), am i right?

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal Yes, just a new copy of the project. It's the easiest and safest way. Another way is [Suspend / shelveset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets), then get the latest/specific version, but you need to resolve the conflicts with your local changes, that means you may lose your local changes.